# BouncyCastle Timestamp with OCSP embedded

Tags: c#, timestamp, bouncycastle, ocsp

There:

I am building TimeStamp Authorization by BouncyCastle (c#), everything is ok, however, I can't figure out how I can embed OCSP response when sign by timestamp key, by default, it just use CRL which defined in timestamp certificate.

```
TimeStampTokenGenerator tokenGen = new TimeStampTokenGenerator(theIssuerPrivateKey, cert, TspAlgorithms.Sha512, "1.2");

                IList certList = new ArrayList();
                certList.Add(cert);

                IX509Store x509Certs = X509StoreFactory.Create("Certificate/Collection", new X509CollectionStoreParameters(certList));
                tokenGen.SetCertificates(x509Certs);

                TimeStampRequestGenerator reqGen = new TimeStampRequestGenerator();
                reqGen.SetCertReq(true);
                TimeStampRequest req = reqGen.Generate(TspAlgorithms.Sha512, content);

                TimeStampResponseGenerator respGen = new TimeStampResponseGenerator(tokenGen, TspAlgorithms.Allowed);
                TimeStampResponse resp = respGen.Generate(req, new BigInteger("23"), signTime);

                //embedded some ocsp response to tokenGen maybe? But how?
```

Please help....

Comment: A timestamp does not include any CRL / OCSP response. Validation of the server certificate is done once you get the time stamp with a request to the issuing Certificate authority

Comment: Thanks, so, how can I embed timestamp OCSP response to the signature?

Comment: depends on the signature format. I guess with BouncyCastle you use CMS. If you follow the CAdES standard, which uses CMS, the time stamp and the OCSP response are included in the signature itself encoded in ASN.1

Comment: Thanks pedrofb, I will have a check for that, I also found method "SetCrls" in "TimeStampTokenGenerator", did implemention, but it's no help.